# javascript frame navigation in ie11 with a pdf

Tags: javascript, pdf, internet-explorer-11, frames

I have a simple web page where 1 frame displays a pdf and another a menu bar.

```
<iframe src="bar.html" name="menu"  ></iframe>
<iframe src="doc.pdf" name="itempane"   ></iframe>
```

Using chrome I can navigate from the menu bar  to the parent and back down to the frame containing the pdf in order to print it

```
var pWindow = window.parent;
pWindow['itempane'].print();
```

Attempting to do the same in IE11 gives an Invalid calling object error.

you can see this at http://www.abhrdev.co.uk/main.html

What am I doing wrong / what is IE doing differently?

Cheers

Updated.....

I think I have proved that this is not a javascript coding issue but related to the pdf handling in  IE.  With the following page

```
<a href="javascript:printFromMain('pdfpane');">Print PDF</a><br/>
<a href="javascript:printFromMain('htmlpane');">Print HTML</a>
<iframe src="bar_1.html" name="menu"  ></iframe>
<iframe src="doc.pdf" name="pdfpane"   ></iframe>
<iframe src="doc.html" name="htmlpane"   ></iframe>
```

and this function

```
function printFromMain(paneName) {
var pWindow = window[paneName];
pWindow.focus();
pWindow.print();
}
```

the printing of the html page works but not the pdf the pWindow.focus() gives Invalid Calling Object - any insight into why that might be greatfully recieved

Comment: minor note on your sample link... I don't think it is the root cause but your page is missing a `<body>` tag.

Comment: @mplungjan The call is coming from an iframe so it needs the parent.

Comment: thanks both, body tag added and doctype change to tidy it up.
    window["itempane"].print();
gives
    Unable to get property 'print' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 1):

After trying several things, I finally go this to work in IE11:

1) use an object tag instead of iframe

2) run focus() / print() directly on the element

3) run after a timeout, to make sure everything in  is loaded. There may be a better way (like using some event listener) to do this, as the timeout time needs to be fairly long for it to work properly

```
setTimeout(function () {
    var contentThingy = document.getElementById('itempane');
    contentThingy.focus();
    contentThingy.print();
}, 4000);
```

Object (with a specified id) instead of iframe:

```
<object id="itempane" ... ></object>
```

Note:  doesn't work in chrome.  One of the other variations in the other answers (i.e. using ContentWindow) may.

Answer (score 0):

Try actually using the [window.frames](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.frames) to get the frameList and reference it by the frame name that way.

```
var pWindow = window.parent;  //reference the parent from the iframe
var ifr = pWindow.frames.itempane;  //get the pdf frame from the frame list
ifr.focus();  
ifr.print();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<iframe src="bar.html" name="menu"  ></iframe>
<iframe src="doc.pdf" ID="itempane"   ></iframe>


var otherPane = parent.document.getElementById("itempane");
otherPane.focus(); // OR
otherPane.print(); // OR

var doc = otherPane.contentWindow || otherPane.contentDocument;
doc.focus();
doc.print();
```

Comment: I'll try today on the 11