# IE9+ gives Invalid calling object error when calling focus() on contentWindow of an iframe

Tags: javascript, asp.net, pdf, iframe, printing

I have this javascript fuction, I use it to print pdf document contained in an iframe:

```
  function printFrame1() {
      var frm = window.frames["IfPol_app"]; // or document.getElementById("IfPol_app").contentWindow
      frm.focus();// focus on contentWindow is needed on some ie versions
      frm.print();

  }
```

the iframe element is like this:

```
<iframe runat="server" id="IfPol_app" frameborder="0" width="100%" height="630px" />
```

The browsers (chrome, firefox, IE8-) print window shows up with the pdf, IE9+ gives me this error on the focus() method call:

> 0x8000ffff - JavaScript runtime error: Invalid calling object

I searched all related topics to contentWindow, contentDocument, iframe, pdf printing but i couldn't find a solution to this problem, can any one help please.

thank you

Comment: Have you checked, what `frm` actually is?

Comment: frm is the contentWindow, its just my colleague at work who named it like that

Comment: Again: have you checked that `frm` really refers to the "contentWindow"? If you put `console.log(frm)` immediately after `var` line, what you see?

Comment: this guy here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25870970/javascript-frame-navigation-in-ie11-with-a-pdf has the same problem as i have, here is demo http://www.abhrdev.co.uk/main.html

Comment: i get the same error with both console.log(frm) and alert(frm)

Comment: The demo doesn't show anything in the iframe in IE11... Anyway, sounds like the plug-in you use for showing pdfs  would take over the whole iframe, and somehow override the window object.

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, i gess no one found yet a solution or a workaround for this issue, i searched all day but no luck

Comment: I tried to open the pdf in a popup window then call print() on it, this time i've got this error "0x800a0046 - JavaScript runtime error: Permission denied" on the print call

Comment: This is also occurring on IE11 as well.  The lack of information on this problem is really disturbing.